# should shutdown all mongods on the same machine when I use "apt-get install" to upgrade mongodb

Tags: mongodb, continuous-deployment

I plan to setup one config mongo server and one mongo server (among the 3-server shard) on the same machine. If so, I need 3 machines to have 3 config servers, and several shards. And I prefer to use `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org` to upgrade to the new mongodb version.

Should I shut down all the mongods on the same machine before I run this command? I am confused because in the doc it is suggested to upgrade query routers firstly, then config serves, and shards lastly. Reference: [Upgrade to the Latest Revision of MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/upgrade-revision/#upgrade-sharded-cluster)

Comment: You don't need to shut down the other mongo* processes on the same machine if you're careful to only upgrade one binary at a time. You obviously don't want to try and upgrade a running mongo* to a new binary.

Comment: I am confused. If all the mongo* processes are on the same machine, and I would like to upgrade to a new binary, should I stop all of them. Otherwise, what should I do?

Comment: It seems that I used the same binary for the config server instance and the data server instance.

Comment: Same binary with different data directories? Then you'll have to take both down to be safe. For the record, best not to have the config server and data server colocated for prod.

Comment: I already know how to do now. Thanks. I plan to mkdir two filefolds in the /usr/bin/ directory to hold two binaries for config server and data server. Each time, sudo apt-get install can upgrade the binary in /usr/bin/ to newest version. Then I can copy them to my filefolds to upgrade the config server and data server. Is it right? Do you have better idea?

Comment: That seems fine, but you'll need to handle startup scripts, etc.